# sympy: dsolve for a system of differential equations

Tags: syntax, sympy, calculus

How can I solve a system of ode's?

That's what I've tried:

```
from sympy import *;
init_printing()

Ex,Ey,Ez,Bx,By,Bz,c,m0,t,u,we,wb,q=symbols('E_x E_y E_z B_x B_y B_z c m_0 t u omega_E omega_B q')
tau=dynamicsymbols('tau')

u0=Function('u^0')(tau) 
u1=Function('u^1')(tau)
u2=Function('u^2')(tau)
u3=Function('u^3')(tau) # edit

u=Matrix([u0,u1,u2,u3])
Emat=Matrix([[0,Ex/c,Ey/c,Ez/c],[Ex/c,0,Bz,-By],[Ey/c,-Bz,0,Bx],[Ez/c,By,-Bx,0]])
RHS=q/m0*Emat*u

odesys=[Eq(u0.diff(),RHS[0]),Eq(u1.diff(),RHS[1]),Eq(u2.diff(),RHS[2]),Eq(u3.diff(),RHS[3])]
odesys
dsolve(odesys,[u0(tau),u1(tau),u2(tau),u3(tau)])
```

Unfortunately it gives me a TypeError:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-f4af1f7e485c> in <module>()
     16 odesys=[Eq(u0.diff(),RHS[0]),Eq(u1.diff(),RHS[1]),Eq(u2.diff(),RHS[2]),Eq(u3.diff(),RHS[3])]
     17 odesys
---> 18 dsolve(odesys,[u0(tau),u1(tau),u2(tau),u3(tau)])

TypeError: 'u^0' object is not callable
```

I've tried so many things, but I just can't figure out the proper syntax for this to work.
Any ideas?

BTW: It doesn't help if I use dynamicsymbols instead of functions:

```
...
u0,u1,u2,u3=dynamicsymbols('u^0 u^1 u^2 u^3')
...
dsolve(odesys,[u0(t),u1(t),u2(t),u3(t)])
```

-> Same TypeError

EDIT: 
I made it a little bit easier for dsolve and only asked it to solve for the 1st equation (out of 4) while keeping my Function definitions:

```
dsolve(Eq(u0.diff(),RHS[0]))
```

-> This actually worked.

Next step: solve for 1st and 2nd equation:

```
dsolve([Eq(u0.diff(),RHS[0]),Eq(u1.diff(),RHS[1])])
```

-> "...Not Implemented Error"

This is an everyday kind of problem for physicists. Better stick with Mathematica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write `u0=Function('u^0')(tau)` which means that `u0` is the function with symbol "u^0" with "tau" passed in as the argument. Then `u0(t)` does not make sense; you already said what the argument of the function is. It's like writing u^0(tau)(t), does not make sense.

So, either have `u0=Function('u^0')` without an argument (and then provide it in the equations) or change `u0(t)` to `u0`.

You also have a typo in the definition of `u3` which makes it identical to `u0`.

Lastly, the whole thing with tau being a function of t and also the argument of an unknown function in a differential equation is murky. You are differentiating with respect to a function, which is hard enough for people to understand, let alone computers.

I suggest stating the system so that it's clear what the independent variable is, and that the derivatives are taken in that variable.

#### Example of solving a simple ODE system in SymPy

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols('t')
x = Function('x')(t)
y = Function('y')(t)
sol = dsolve([x.diff() - y, y.diff() + x])
```

gets you `[Eq(x(t), C1*sin(t) + C2*cos(t)), Eq(y(t), C1*cos(t) - C2*sin(t))]`.

Comment: "... Then u0(t) does not make sense; you already said what the argument of the function is. It's like writing u^0(tau)(t), does not make sense.. " ->  I just copied the wrong version of my script. It doesn't work both ways. "So, either have u0=Function('u^0') without an argument" -> This doesn't work...I'm getting a lot of complains due to the matrix multiplication.  "You also have a typo in the definition of u3 which makes it identical to u0." -> Thanks for that hint, but it actually doesn't change anything. My last question: Is sympy able to solve ODE-systems at all?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is terribly out of date, but I am working on moving things from Maple to Python and stumbled on this post.  With some rearrangement, I was able to get it to come up with a "solution" for up to the first three equations; once I put the fourth in, Python seems to hang:

```
#%%
from sympy import *
init_printing()

#%%
Ex,Ey,Ez,Bx,By,Bz,c,m0,t,u,we,wb,q=symbols(
    'E_x E_y E_z B_x B_y B_z c m_0 t u omega_E omega_B q', 
    real=True, positive=True)

#%%
u0=Function('u^0')
u1=Function('u^1')
u2=Function('u^2')
u3=Function('u^3')

#%%
u=Matrix([u0(t),u1(t),u2(t),u3(t)])
Emat=Matrix([
    [0,Ex/c,Ey/c,Ez/c],
    [Ex/c,0,Bz,-By],
    [Ey/c,-Bz,0,Bx],
    [Ez/c,By,-Bx,0]])
RHS=q/m0*Emat@u

#%%
odesys=[
    Eq(u0(t).diff(t),RHS[0]),
    Eq(u1(t).diff(t),RHS[1]),
    Eq(u2(t).diff(t),RHS[2]),
    Eq(u3(t).diff(t),RHS[3])]

#%%
for k in range(1, 5):    
    print("{} equations".format(k))
    soln = dsolve(odesys[0:k])
    pretty_print(soln)
```

I have not done any rigorous checking about whether the assertions about real or positive matter...  Also, the "solutions" for the first three contain integrals for whichever variables are left out so calling them "solutions" is a stretch but at least Python did *something*  :)  And oh what a something it is - here's u^0 with three equations:

[image: u0 for three equations]